# Unable to format external HDD

Tags: storage, disk-format

When creating a partition with GUID Partition Map Scheme in Disk Utility, I'm getting "Partition failed with the error: Unable to write to the last block of the device". Same message when I try to erase the whole volume. Same for formatting for Mac OS Extended *Encrypted*.

Trying to [write to the disk from /dev/random](http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/05/how-to-fix-deep-formatting-problems-with-os-x-drives/) prior to formatting doesn't change anything.

Filling with zeroes:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1
dd: /dev/disk1: Resource busy
```

...and later:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1
dd: /dev/disk1: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.250087 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

Running diskutil:

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ "ext" /dev/disk1
Started erase on disk1
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device
```

After all this, Windows sees the disk as an empty HFS volume, but when I try to re-format it with Windows Explorer, it reports: `"Windows was unable to complete the format"`.

[Using](http://www.iphonetopics.com/unable-to-write-to-the-last-block-of-the-device/) diskpart under Windows, "format" action remained stuck at 0% for 2 hours (which for a 500GB looks should be definitely "frozen"):

```
DISKPART> clean
DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> create partition primary
DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> active
DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> select partition 1
Partition 1 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> active    
DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check).
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> format fs=fat32

    0 percent completed
```

Trying to format with Computer Management > Disk Management: `The format did not complete successfully.`

Running multiple `diskutil eraseDisk`, [per Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/unable-to-format-external-hdd?noredirect=1#comment249551_206815):

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS FAT MBRFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for the disks to reappear
Formatting disk2s1 as MS-DOS (FAT) with name FAT
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk2s1: 976534720 sectors in 15258355 FAT32 clusters (32768 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=64 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf8 spt=32 hds=255 hid=2 drv=0x80 bsec=976773166 bspf=119206 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=6
Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2s1 with name FAT after erase
Finished erase on disk2

$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ macfs GPTFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device

$ diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS FAT MBRFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device

$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ macfs GPTFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device

$ diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS FAT MBRFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device

$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ macfs GPTFormat disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device
```

Comment: What are you writing to? If ever I get that "Unable to write to the last block of the device" error on SD Cards they just go in the bin; already too far gone to be worth the effort. I handle hundreds of SD Cards for work, so my attitude to them is rather cavalier, but they're not worth fighting once they start to go bad. One trick is to format GUID/HFS, then MBR/FAT16 [or 32, depending on size] Sometimes gets one more round out of them. Whatever you do, don't put anything mission-critical on one.

Comment: External HDD, in an USB 3.0 enclosure connected to USB 2.0 of Macbook Air mid-2011 13" / Macbook Pro late-2010 13". The enclosure works fine with another HDD. @Tetsujin

Comment: "to format GUID/HFS, then MBR/FAT16 [or 32, depending on size]" -- just tried that with OS X for GUID/HFS, then with Windows for MBR/FAT32. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The 'trick' is to do the opposite of what you want, then what you want it to be, just to try shake things up a bit. I would do it all in Disk Utility, not swap between Mac & Win. I usually do it from Applescript, cmd to do MBR/FAT32 would be `do shell script "diskutil eraseDisk \"MS-DOS\" " & diskName & " MBRFormat disk6"` [make sure the disk6 is the appropriate device

Comment: Updated the question with the output. Still "Unable to write to the last block of the device" repeatedly. @Tetsujin

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty much out of ideas, except maybe to try find the drive manufacturer's own formatting tool & give that a go